# unknown column 'extent3.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am getting following error

```
unknown column 'extent3.id' in 'where clause'
```

when I am adding following line into `automapper.cs` config file.

```
.ForMember(d => d.hq_state, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.firm_address.Where(c
 => (c.record_status != DeleteStatus && c.is_hq==true)).FirstOrDefault().ab_state_name))



x.CreateMap<firm, SupplierAutoCompleteDTO>()
                 .ForMember(d => d.display_name, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.name))
                 .ForMember(d => d.firm_contacts, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.firm_contacts.Where(c => c.record_status != DeleteStatus)))
                 .ForMember(d => d.hq_state, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.firm_address.Where(c => (c.record_status != DeleteStatus && c.is_hq==true)).FirstOrDefault().ab_state_name))
                 .ForMember(d => d.supplier_status, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.mst_firm_status.name));
```

Comment: View mysql database and verify the column exist in the database.

Comment: its exists , I doubled checked  and its like a known bug of MySQL connector with EF , now I am looking for some suggestion here to how can I change this mapping into different LINQ syntax that don't produce error.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69922

Comment: The link you provided is an error when a DateTime value is null.  You are having an issue with an ID.  The link is from 2013/2014 and old bugs like that were fixed a long time ago.  Some similar error can be caused by CORE.  but this doesn't look like a CORE error.

Comment: but if i remove this line .ForMember(d => d.hq_state, m => m.MapFrom(o => o.firm_address.Where(c
 => (c.record_status != DeleteStatus && c.is_hq==true)).FirstOrDefault().ab_state_name)) there will be no error and yes this column exists in DB and EF model as well.

Comment: There is a mapping file (mdbx) that maps the c# classes to the database.  The mapping is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229948/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when MySQL consider the `column value as a column name`. Let me explain with an example:

Create a simple table:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE T1 (id int, name varchar(200), city varchar(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)
```

Insert some records:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO T1 values (1, 'rathish', 'ooty');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO T1 values (2, 'kumar', 'the nilgiris');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

Now lets try to update a record:

```
mysql> UPDATE T1 SET name = 'rathish kumar' WHERE name = `rathish`;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'rathish' in 'where clause'
```

This happens when I am using **`backtick`** **(`)** around column value.

Lets try with single quotes or double quotes:

```
mysql> UPDATE T1 SET name = 'rathish kumar b' WHERE name = 'rathish';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

It works!!! Lets check one more scenario:

```
mysql> UPDATE T1 SET name = 'rathish kumar b' WHERE name = kumar;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'kumar' in 'where clause'
```

No quotes here, same error. Lets check one more scenario:

```
mysql> UPDATE T1 SET name = 'rathish kumar b' WHERE id = kumar;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'kumar' in 'where clause'
```

Again MySQL thinks, it is a column name. So my guess is, `extent3.id` column is surrounded with `backticks` or trying to assign `value with a data type which is not id data type and without quotes`.

```
WHERE extent3.id = `value`; # backtick - value considered as column name
```

(OR)

```
WHERE extent3.id = value; # without quotes - value considered as column name
```

It needs to be:

```
WHERE extent3.id = 'value'; # single or double quotes - for string type
```

OR

```
WHERE extent3.id = 100; # for int type
```

Fixing this will help resolve this error, try and let us know if it helps. If not, share the generated query for further analysis. Thank you!